# Message inbox missing - No notifications

Tags: adminhtml, admin-panel, messages, notification, adminnotification

The message inbox is missing in two of our shops (Magento 2.4.2). We can not see messages and do not have the notification bell on the top right (see screenshot).
There are entries in the admin_system_messages table and when adding new messages programmatically it just writes a database entry, but shows no notifications and the bell is still missing.

The Magento_AdminNotification module is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Enable Magento_AdminNotification module?

Comment: It is enabled. I will add this Info to the question.